# Three js cube layers

Tags: javascript, three.js

3 Problems: 1. I want to get 27 mini cubes in one big cube so i can get effect like on the picture below.

---

2.How can i get data of each mini cube? By data i mean, width, height, depth. In canvas its easy since all you need to do is to put into `var` `canvas.width` or height.

---

3.
The effect i want to achieve is like this pic: [image: Transparent Rubik Cube]

I dont understand how layers work in `three.js`. I've tried to add "3d" array by nesting 3 `for` loops to have position of each mini cube. I want to make A* algorithm through it, so thats why I would like to get data of each mini cube.

So far I have only 1, transparent with white borders, big cube and I dont see creating 27 new objects with copy-paste without any x, y, z data to put into. Any help/tips will be highly appreciated and considered!

Comment: CHeck out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848707/three-js-arranging-cubes-in-a-grid/32850374#32850374 as a hint for for arranging the cubes for your #1 - each cube will have its own data as .position etc for your #2, just ask for cubeMesh.position etc - but your #3 isn't even a question so I've no idea how to respond. Are you trying to raytrace? Analyze values volumetric data? No idea what you mean by "run A* algorithm through it" -- what paths are you trying to map?

Comment: Hmm, indeed that was really helpfull. I've managed to do this: http://imgur.com/cLkehG8 
Now the thing is.. when i'm calling for example `console.log(mesh14.position);` i'm receiving 5 logs, but i have `for(var i=0; i<5; i++)` loop. Any logic here? Also, since each pillar of cubes is in this loop, how could i get data for specific cube? Should I use array there?

Comment: Ahh, tunnel vision with this `for` loop. Found the problem after changing the background color.